# What is the latest xcode for Mac Pro 10.6.7 Snow Leopard?

Tags: xcode, osx-snow-leopard

all,

I noticed the latest xcode is 4.6, but somehow it won't install on my old Mac Pro 10.6.7 Snow Leopard. I am wondering how can I get it work? Do I need to upgrade my Mac OS? Or what is the latest xcode version I can run on my Mac Pro?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The latest you can run on 10.6 is Xcode 4.2. If you update to 10.7 or 10.8 you can run Xcode 4.6.

Comment: I guess I will do OS upgrade first. Can I upgrade my 10.6 directly to 10.8?

Comment: Awesome. Let me try that out and see how it goes! Thanks.

Comment: When I do the check upgrade on OS about window, it only shows 10.6.8. After I upgrade to 10.6.8 and check it again, it no longer shows any other upgrade. Is this supposed the way to upgrade to 10.8?

Comment: @user518138 You have to buy Lion or Mountain Lion from the Mac App Store.  If you create a paid Developer Account with Apple you get free O/S version updates.

Comment: @user518138 it might as well be that your hardware is not supported by the latest OSX version, which will lead to you not being able to install it on top of your current OS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to leave your OS on 10.6.7 Snow leopard then the latest Xcode you can run is 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Either upgrade your Mac OS for XCode4.6

or

Use XCode 3.2, this will work like a charm.